# How to close terminal without shutting down Android emulator booted from terminal

Tags: android, emulation

I understand that any process started from the command line is attached to the command line process, so when I close my terminal, any processes started from that shell process will be killed.

So if I want to boot an emulator

```
emulator -av emu1 -ports 5000,5000 &
```

which creates the background emulator process, but emulator will still die if I close the terminal.

How can I boot emulator such that emulator wont get killed after I close terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent any process that was started from a terminal being killed when the terminal the process was launched from is closed, you need to prefix the emulator command with ***nohup*** or ***setsid***.
***nohup*** is short for no hang-ups, and you will probably want to redirect output to /dev/null otherwise it wants to generate a *nohup.out* file. The ampersand & at the end causes the command to be run as a background process.  Usage example:

```
$ nohup ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_29_x86 >/dev/null &
```

***setsid*** runs a process or program in a new session preventing the process/program being killed when the terminal it was launched from is closed. Usage example:

```
$ sudo setsid ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_29_x86
```

Note: On my system, I had to first cd into ***~/Android/Sdk/emulator*** to run the emulator, in case any one tries to run the emulator from the command line right out of the box and gets a command not found error.

see the man pages for ***nohup*** or ***setsid*** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `screen`. Install it if it's not already

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Start screen

```
screen
```

After the screen session has started, issue your command

```
emulator -av emu1 -ports 5000,5000
```

Detach session by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

Exit the terminal and open a new one just to verify. Reattach the running session

```
screen -r
```

Comment: Sure, but say I booted the emulator from Android Studio. I close Android Studio, the emulator doesn't shut down. Maybe I need to "detach" the emulator process from the terminal before I close the terminal?

Comment: If you start it from Android studio it starts as a separate process that's not attached to the Android studio process. You could detach the process immediately by using `screen -dm emulator -av emu1 -ports 5000,5000` or check out @Steve's answer

Answer (score 0):

**Starting Android emulator from the terminal, such that it won't get killed after closing the terminal.**

If we start Android emulator using ampersand (&) at the end of line, it will kill itself after closing the terminal.
To solve this we can use `screen` with special parameters `-dm`

```
screen -dm emulator <emulator parameters>
```

If screen is not installed: `sudo install screen`

from man page

> -dm Start  screen  in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

Originally, this command mentioned by [@Misantorp](https://askubuntu.com/users/844123/misantorp), as a comment to his answer.